# Convert/Port PDWORD code in C#

Tags: c#, c++, arrays, integer

I'm converting some code from C++ to C#, and I need some insight on how to deal with lines like these:

```
PDWORD rgb32_data = (PDWORD) malloc(640*480*4);
```

From what I understand, the `PDWORD` type represents an unsigned integer (32bit). What would be a good C# strategy to implement a similar structure?

EDIT: I figured out that I need to use an IntPtr to replace the PDWORD, but the IntPtr would hold a single value as opposed to many values as in an array. Any C# suggestions?

EDIT2: Uint[]s don't work for me - unfortunately, the only way I can make the program compile, with all its dependencies, is when I enter an IntPtr as a the argument, not an IntPtr[].

Thanks.

EDIT - I've marked the solution, in addition I needed to do the following:

Since I needed an IntPtr cast, I added this code

```
        IntPtr rgb32_ptr; 
        GCHandle handle = GCHandle.Alloc(rgb32_data, GCHandleType.Pinned);
        try
        {
            rgb32_ptr = handle.AddrOfPinnedObject();
        }
        finally
        {
            if (handle.IsAllocated)
            {
                handle.Free();
            }
        }
```

to get an IntPtr to the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb401689.aspx), `PDWORD` is defined as:

```
typedef DWORD*  PDWORD;
```

So it's a pointer to a `DWORD`, which MSDN [also says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc230318%28v=prot.10%29.aspx) is an unsigned 32-bit integer - in other words, a `uint`.

Note that your line of C++ code allocates memory for an array of 640 * 480 = 307,200 `DWORD`s.

You could translate this directly as:

```
uint[] rgb32_data = new uint[640 * 480];
```

But the code might really want to use it as just a series of bytes in memory, so you might instead want to use a byte array

```
byte[] rgb32_data = new byte[640 * 480 * 4];
```

and use the methods in the [BitConverter class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.aspx) (especially the [`ToInt32()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.toint32.aspx) method) if you think that is closer to how the original program handles the data.

Comment: Good catch. I should have realized that he's looking to allocate an array. Since the original code makes it `PDWORD`, I suspect the first--an array of unsigned ints.

Comment: Yeah, this is what I've done. In addition to this, since I needed an IntPtr cast, I added this code 

 GCHandle handle = GCHandle.Alloc(rgb32Source, GCHandleType.Pinned);
            try
            {
                rgb32_data = handle.AddrOfPinnedObject();
            }
            finally
            {
                if (handle.IsAllocated)
                {
                    handle.Free();
                }
            }

Answer (score 2):

You can use unsafe pointers and `Marshal.AllocHGlobal()`

```
    Program()
    {            
        unsafe
        {
            IntPtr ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(640 * 480 * 4);

            uint* ptr2 = (uint*)ptr.ToPointer();

            for (int i = 0; i < 640*480; i++)
            {
                ptr2[i] = 0;
            }

            Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

PDWORD is a pointer to a 32-bit unsigned integer. In C#, that would be `ref uint32`. Or `IntPtr` if you're on the 32-bit runtime.

It depends on how you're going to use it. If you're passing it to unmanaged code, then I'd suggest the `ref UInt32`. If you're using it for memory allocation (the return value from a Windows API function that allocates memory, for example), then you'd want to use `IntPtr`.

Comment: How would I use IntPtr? I added this to my edit. Wouldn't IntPtr just give me a single value? What kind of referencing could I use?

Comment: @sparkFinder: You just need to allocate an array. The answer by Lucas Jones is probably what you're looking for.

Comment: That's what I did initially - unfortunately, the only way I can make the program compile, with all its dependencies, is when I enter an IntPtr as a the argument, not an IntPtr[]

Comment: @sparkFinder: I can't imagine having to use an array of `IntPtr` here. Can you give us more context?

Comment: Its tough for me to do so, just that the method that ends up taking rgb32_data as an argument needs an IntPtr as its argument. How would I be able to package my code using one? I was thinking of using an IntPtr[] instead of the uint[]  that has also been suggested here, but I can only use an IntPtr (which is what my previous comment was trying to say). I'm new to C# so I just might be missing out on some key concept. Cheers :)

Comment: error CS1502: The best overloaded method match for 'GetCameraColorFrameRGB32(System.IntPtr, System.IntPtr, int)' has some invalid arguments
error CS1503: Argument 2: cannot convert from 'uint*' to 'System.IntPtr'

Comment: Are the errors I get - the second parameter is the subject here, and needs to be chopped into an IntPtr.

Comment: @sparkFinder: Without some sample code and a bit of description of what you're trying to do, I can't be of much help. What is the `rgb32_data` for, what functions are you passing it to, etc? Can you edit your question to add some detail, and post some code that shows what you need to do with the 1grg32_data`?

Answer (score 0):

PDWORD is a pointer to a DWORD.  There are a few options to convert the code to C# depending on how it will be used.

For the DWORD itself you can use System.UInt32 as an equivalent.  Marshal.AllocHGlobal might be a possibility as a replacement, but we would need to see how it's going to be used.  Are you accessing the memory yourself or maybe passing it to another unmanaged function?